# How do these LISP expressions evaluate to the answer provided?

Tags: lisp

Now, just by looking at the question and the variables `L` and `X`, I can see, more or less, at the very minimum how these answers come to fruition.

But this time I would like to know the inner workings, step by step, as to how these answers come about.  My professor is absolutely terrible and can't explain anything for his life.

```
L = (D B B A A A A C)
X = ((2B) (4A) (1C))

Q1) (cons (list (+ (caar X) 1) (cadar X)) (cdr X))
Answer: ((3B) (4A) (1C))

Q2) (cons (list 1 (car L)) X)
Answer: ((1D) (2B) (4A) (1C))
```

Comment: This is the second time you ask a question where you complain about your teacher/professor. Please avoid rants in your questions, keep only the details that are directly relevant to the question and the one that can help us answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't miss spaces in the definition of `X`?
Looks like, it should be defined like this:

```
X = ((2 B) (4 A) (1 C))
```

The computation is like this:

```
;;; Setup.
(defvar L '(D B B A A A A C))
(defvar X '((2 B) (4 A) (1 C)))

;;; Q1:
(cons (list (+ (caar X) 1) (cadar X)) (cdr X))
;;;            ^^^^^^^^
;;; (caar X) = 2
(cons (list (+ 2 1) (cadar X)) (cdr X))
;;;         ^^^^^^^
;;; (+ 2 1) = 3
(cons (list 3 (cadar X)) (cdr X))
;;;           ^^^^^^^^^
;;; (cadar X) = B
(cons (list 3 'B) (cdr X))
;;;   ^^^^^^^^^^^
;;; (list 3 'B) = (3 B)
(cons '(3 B) (cdr X))
;;;          ^^^^^^^
;;; (cdr X) = ((4 A) (1 C))

    (cons '(3 B) '((4 A) (1 C)))
;;; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;;; (cons '(3 B) '((4 A) (1 C))) = ((3 B) (4 A) (1 C))
'((3 B) (4 A) (1 C))

;;; Q2:
(cons (list 1 (car L)) X)
;;;           ^^^^^^^
;;; (car L) = D
(cons (list 1 'D) X)
;;;   ^^^^^^^^^^^
;;; (list 1 'D) = (1 D)

    (cons '(1 D) X)
;;; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;;; (cons '(1 D) X) = ((1 D) (2 B) (4 A) (1 C))
'((1 D) (2 B) (4 A) (1 C))
```